How do I load the saved keras weights from an .h5 file
I am trying to replicate an example of image classification - training, validation and then finally test on a standalone image sample.
I saved the weights (only) using:
model.save_weights('file_name.h5')

Now, in order to run prediction, I want to load the saved .h5 file for which I am trying:
Model.load_weights('file_name.h5')

The file file_name.h5 is saved in the same root path.
However, I am getting error

TypeError: load_weights() missing 1 required positional argument:
'filepath'

What should I do in order the load the saved weight.
There is a discussion in this respect here at the keras page

there is a typo, model vs Model, you are not calling the correct variable

Just to close the stupid question (can't delete it) (besides typho_s):
Here is what I would do.

After creating a model:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Activation('relu'))
...
...
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))


Load the weights:
model.load_weights(<path_to_file>)


